SOQL Injection possible - Sonarqube
I'm not able to fix this Sonarqube issue related to SOQL Injection possible, this is original code,
AggregateResultIterator class is called in Batch start method:
global without sharing class AggregateResultIterator implements Iterator<AggregateResult> {
    AggregateResult [] results {get;set;}
    // tracks which result item is returned
    Integer index {get; set;} 
    
    global AggregateResultIterator(String query) {
        index = 0;
        results = Database.query(query);
        // results = Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(query));
        System.debug('results: ' +results);
    } 
    
    global boolean hasNext() { 
        return results != null && !results.isEmpty() && index < results.size(); 
    }    
    
    global AggregateResult next() {        
        return results[index++];            
    }     
}

startDateFormat = String.valueOf(startDate);
endDateFormat = String.valueOf(endDate);
        
String query =  ' SELECT OpportunityLineItemId, SUM(Revenue) Revenue,  '+
                        ' OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.AccountId, '+
                        ' Order_Item__r.Supplying_Entity__c, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Legal_Entity_Account__c '+
                        ' FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule '+
                        ' WHERE OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.StageName = \'Closed Won\' AND ScheduleDate >= '+ startDateFormat +' AND ScheduleDate <= ' + endDateFormat +
                        ' GROUP BY OpportunityLineItemId, OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.AccountId,' +
                        ' Order_Item__r.Supplying_Entity__c, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Legal_Entity_Account__c ';

return new AggregateResultIterable(query);

Issue comes with line results = Database.query(query).
So I have tried many solutions but I can't get them to work.
#1. Use String.escapeSingleQuotes(query) method, but this one results in this error --> System.QueryException: line 1:310 no viable alternative at character ''
#2. I am trying to clean function result like this:
String field1 = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(getSomeId()) + '\'';
String field2 = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE isPublic = true and Id = ';
Database.query(field2 + field1);

But I keep getting this error --> line 1:310 no viable alternative at character ''
If anyone could help with this issue it will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

In general - use proper bind variables so you don't have issues with \'.
In this particular case I'd rewrite your WHERE IsClosed = true AND IsWon = true (most orgs have just 1 status that means "closed won" but in theory you can have more).
If you want to keep it closer to the original:
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
Set<String> statuses = new Set<String>{'Closed Won'};
        
String query =  ' SELECT OpportunityLineItemId, SUM(Revenue) Revenue,  '+
                        ' OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.AccountId, '+
                        ' Order_Item__r.Supplying_Entity__c, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Legal_Entity_Account__c '+
                        ' FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule '+
                        ' WHERE OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.StageName IN :statuses AND ScheduleDate >= :startDate AND ScheduleDate <= :endDate' +
                        ' GROUP BY OpportunityLineItemId, OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.AccountId,' +
                        ' Order_Item__r.Supplying_Entity__c, OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Legal_Entity_Account__c ';

There's some more reading what to do if the variables you bind to aren't in same context (are visible in the place where you used to hand-craft the query string but they don't exist in the place where actual Database.query() is called), check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm out.
And similarly I'd also do binds in your
Id i = getSomeId();
String q = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE isPublic = true and Id = :i';
Database.query(q);


Hi I have tried to implement what you are saying, but I keep getting errors in AggregateResultIterator class for 'Variable does not exist', even if I put Closed won stage as a final static field and pass it in query with bind variable, so not sure how to solve this at the end.

edit the question with the updated code? Any special reason you use the Iterator variant of batch jobs instead of plain QueryLocator?
